# 'Project creation failed' when creating new Smart Device application

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm running Visual Studio 2008 Professional Version 9.0.30729.1 and am having a serious problem creating a new Smart Device project in either C# or VB.net.

I get the following error when I try to create a new Smart Device application from template:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object ... and a 'project creation failed' message in the status bar.

I have uninstalled and install VS 2008 software from my machine but can't seem to find the cause of this problem.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how I could resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved myself.

Reinstall Microsoft Compact Framework 3.5 Redistribute. And work again.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this exact problem with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (Windows 7 64 bit) which had installed correctly but when I tried to create a new project, I always got the message project creation failed. I couldnt find a solution any where on the internet which worked for me. After debugging, I got the following solution:

First try the solution steps mentioned in http://masteranza.wordpress.com/2008/12/27/solution-vs-c-2008-project-creation-failed-bug
If the above steps solve your problem well and good or move to step 3
Run Regedit as an Administrator. Go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID{f414c260-6ac0-11cf-b6d1-00aa00bbbb58}\InprocServer32
Right click on InprocServer32 .You will notice that only the system account is present. Give Full Control access to the System account if not already present. Now, add your Administrator account (or the account with which you are trying to create the project) and give it Full Control access. Close the Regedit
Now try to create a project again.

Visual Studio tried to open the above registry key which belongs to McAfee (the antivirus on my system), when creating a project. Not sure why it does this, but as the key has a permission issue, it cannot open it.